# Why does my datagridviewcolumn not accept changes at this point?

Tags: .net, datagridview, foreign-keys

I'm bringing down a strongly typed dataset table into a datagridview. then adding a column of combo boxes to let the foreign keys be selected by name instead of ID. Perhaps there's an easier way to do this.

can I transform the typeID column into a comboboxcolumn while still being able to cast the datasource back to my strongly typed dataset table type? Do I need to get it back from the datasource or do changes on the datagridview automatically get passed back to the Dataset?

What's wrong with this code?

```
FormDg fDg;
    internal DsTech.TechObjectsDataTable ShowDg(IWin32Window owner, Db db)
    {
        fDg = new FormDg();

        fDg._dg.DataSource = db.getDs().TechObjects;
        var TypeSelecter = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        var types = db.getdsObjectTypes();
        TypeSelecter.DataSource = types;
        TypeSelecter.DisplayMember = "type";
        TypeSelecter.Name = "Types";
        TypeSelecter.ValueMember = "ID";
        fDg._dg.Columns["typeID"].DisplayIndex=fDg._dg.Columns.Count-1;
        fDg._dg.Columns.Add(TypeSelecter);
        fDg._dg.ReadOnly = false;
        Application.DoEvents();
        for (int i = 0; i < fDg._dg.RowCount; i++)
        {
            if ((fDg._dg.Rows[i].Cells["typeID"].Value is DBNull) == false)
                //Line below does not work
                UpdateTypesRow(i,(int)fDg._dg.Rows[i].Cells["typeID"].Value);
        }
        fDg._dg.CellEndEdit += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(_dg_CellEndEdit);


        if (fDg.ShowDialog(owner) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return (DsTech.TechObjectsDataTable)fDg._dg.DataSource;
        }
        else return null;

    }
```

While this code works just fine

```
void _dg_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (fDg._dg.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Types")
        {
            fDg._dg.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["typeID"].Value = fDg._dg.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Types"].Value;
            //update typeID column

        }
        else if (fDg._dg.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "typeID")
        {
            //update types column
            UpdateTypesRow(e.RowIndex,(int) fDg._dg.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["typeID"].Value);
        }
    }
```

Here's the code I factored the 2 into just in case I was reading wrong and they were actually different

```
    void UpdateTypesRow(int rowIndex, int value)
    {
        fDg._dg.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["Types"].Value = value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using vbforums.com I found examples using binding sources and made sure to add the combo Box before setting the datagridview's datasource property and was able to get this working. [The Thread and code in c#](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=541480)